# Pairing up items of a list according to a predicate in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a list of atoms in Prolog, and a predicate `allowed(X, Y)` that checks whether a pair of items is allowed. How can I take the list and split it into pairs of items, each of which satisfies the predicate? Ideally the pairs would be generated randomly and then checked, but this is only desired.

It can be assumed that the list has an even number of items.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it as follows:

```
checked(_, _, _, N) :-
   N > 5,
   fail.
checked(List, ReturnedList, [X,Y], _) :-
   random_member(X, List),
   select(X, List, List1),
   random_member(Y, List1),
   allowed(X, Y),
   select(Y, List1, ReturnedList).
checked(A, B, C, N) :-
   checked(A, B, C, N+1).

pairMe([], []).
pairMe(List, Result) :-
   checked(List, ReturnedList, [X,Y], 0),
   pairMe(ReturnedList, A),
   append([[X,Y]], A, Result).
```

It's not great, as it doesn't guarantee that it'll always find a result even if one exists, but it works for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

```
pair(L1,L2,(M1,M2)) :-
    member(M1,L1),
    member(M2,L2).
```

Will retrieve, on backtracking, each possible pair. For example:

```
?- pair([1,2,3],[a,b],X).
X = (1, a) ;
X = (1, b) ;
X = (2, a) ;
X = (2, b) ;
X = (3, a) ;
X = (3, b).

?-
```

May be used on a single list, too:

```
?- pair([1,2,3],[1,2,3],X)
```

However, your question is pointless since all allowed pairs are **predefined** by `allowed/2`. You may just retrieve all solutions to allowed/2. So, this is what you are looking for, I guess:

```
allowed_pair(List,(A,B)) :-
    allowed(A,B),
    member(A,List),
    member(B,List).
```

For example, provided that `allowed/2` was defined as:

```
allowed(1,b).
allowed(2,a).
```

Then:

```
?- allowed_pair([1,2,3,a,4,z],X).
X = (2, a) ;
false.

?-
```

Depending on your performance requirements and `allowed/2` implementation, you may exchange order of `allowed_pair/2` goals.

Comment: That's a good, clean solution. I only have one small comment regarding the representation: It is customary to use `(-)/2` to denote pairs, like `A-B`. This is because `,` is already so overloaded in Prolog: It denotes conjunction `(,)/2`, separates predicate arguments etc. Note that `keysort/2` and other library predicates also use `(-)/2` for pairs, and you can use these predicates directly if you follow this convention.